# No predictive text in Phonegap 2.2.0 on Android 4.0.3 with input type="text"

Tags: android, cordova, input, textarea, prediction

I have a PhoneGap app with several fields of `input type="text"`. Besides that it has some HTML textareas.

When running the app on Android and typing text into an HTML `textarea` element, the Android predictive text works fine. However, when I type text into an `input` element of `type="text"` no predictions are shown.

I tested this both on my HTC Sensation and Samsung Galaxy II tablet, both running Android 4.0.3, and the predictive text is not shown on both devices.

This problem can be easily reproduced by adding an `input` element to the example application that is provided by PhoneGap. I tried removing all css to see if that was causing my problem, but the issue remained.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is no longer present in current versions of PhoneGap/Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

I think text prediction depends of the keyboard you are using not the type of input. Check your text suggestions in the settings of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that this works on iOS:

`<input type="text" autocorrect="off" />`

Perhaps it might work on Android as well.

Comment: the question is for android. does your answer work for android?

Comment: @mhlester that's not an awfully useful reply.  A better reply would be "hey this works on Android" or "No, this does not work on Android".

Comment: I'm not the one who wrote the answer. You posted it but don't know yourself whether it is valid? I don't have an android

Comment: @mhlester This is a suggestion as it works for me on iOS and both the OP and myself are using Cordova/Phonegap.